# Can I mix an 8GB chip with a 4GB chip and still get dual channeling?

Tags: memory, ddr3

This is the 4GB version of the chip I want; [Crucial Ballistix Sport 4GB Single DDR3 1600 MT/s (PC3-12800) CL9 @1.5V UDIMM 240-Pin Memory Module BLS4G3D1609DS1S00](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006WAGG14). I have the 8GB version of it already.

Is this a good idea or should I get an 8GB to upgrade to 16GB instead? This is expensive for me, but I could do it.

Also do I need to manually activate dual channeling?

My motherboard has 4 slots. Maybe it would be better to get 2x4?

Comment: Check your motherboard manual it contains the answer to this question

Comment: According to Wikipedia some motherboards don't require matching dimms.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-channel_memory_architecture

Comment: Some motherboards will work in dual channel mode for the portion of memory that matches. So in your case that would be 4GB from each module leaving the second 4GB on the 8GB module accessed in single channel mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, no, they need to be identical enough, or precisely identical chips, which is why they tend to be sold in *kits*. You can't have an 8gb and a 4gb chip and have them in dual channel.

Getting another 8gb chip would probably be the best option, just put it in an appropriate slot (as per your motherboard manual) and you'll have dual channel. While its slightly more expensive, you'd have the benefit of *more* ram and *dual channel*, so its faster.

In general I just buy ram in pairs to start with, and not worry about it.